# CSS issues when hovering over a float element

Tags: html, css, hover, css-float

I'm making a website in CSS with an options element that has 2 options, and the color of the option should change when you hover over it, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFUSc.png). But when I switch to the other side the hover changes the color of the entire bar like it shows [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKaGi.png). I need it to change color just on the half the mouse is hovering over.

Here's my css and html:

```css
#header {
  background-color: #77AD78;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto, Roboto, Roboto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#options {
  background-color: #77AD78;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: #77AD78;
}

#o1 {
  float: left width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#o2 {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6F8F72;
}

#o1:hover {
  background-color: #8FD694;
  color: #77AD78;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Stylish</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylehistoric.css" />
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCp2b5o90_5K1NbK5qZj86P6Hn61xhUFII&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: 11.019343,
          lng: -74.850179
        },
        zoom: 16
      });
      var id1 = document.getElementById('textt');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(id1);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>abcr design</h1>
    <div id="options">
      <div id="o2">Histórico</div>
      <div id="o1"><a href="styletest.php">Tracking</a></div>
    </div>
```

The css for the other page is identical only change is #o2.hover instead of #o1.hover

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `background-color: #77AD78;` on `hover` not the `color`

```css
#header {
  background-color: #77AD78;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto, Roboto, Roboto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  margin:0;
}

#options {
  background-color: #77AD78;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  background-color: #8FD694;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #77AD78;
}

#o1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#o2 {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6F8F72;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>abcr design</h1>
  <div id="options">
    <div id="o2"><a href="#">Histórico</a></div>
    <div id="o1"><a href="styletest.php">Tracking</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing semicolon between float and width:

## o1 {

```
float: left width: 50%;
```

```css
#header {
  background-color: #77AD78;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto, Roboto, Roboto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#options {
  background-color: #77AD78;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: #77AD78;
}

#o1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#o2 {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6F8F72;
}

#o1:hover {
  background-color: #8FD694;
  color: #77AD78;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Stylish</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylehistoric.css" />
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCp2b5o90_5K1NbK5qZj86P6Hn61xhUFII&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: 11.019343,
          lng: -74.850179
        },
        zoom: 16
      });
      var id1 = document.getElementById('textt');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(id1);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>abcr design</h1>
    <div id="options">
      <div id="o2">Histórico</div>
      <div id="o1"><a href="styletest.php">Tracking</a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This css only

```
#header {
  background-color: #77AD78;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto, Roboto, Roboto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#options {
  background-color: #77AD78;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: #77AD78;
}

#o1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#o2 {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6F8F72;
}

#o1:hover {
  background-color: #8FD694;
  color: #77AD78;
} 
#o2:hover {
  background-color: #8FD694;
  color: #77AD78;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#header {
  background-color: #77AD78;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto, Roboto, Roboto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#options {
  background-color: #77AD78;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: #77AD78;
}

#o1 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#o1:hover {
  background-color: #8FD694;
  color: #77AD78;
}

#o2 {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6F8F72;
}

#o2:hover {
  background-color: #8FD694;
  color: #77AD78;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Stylish</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylehistoric.css" />
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCp2b5o90_5K1NbK5qZj86P6Hn61xhUFII&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: 11.019343,
          lng: -74.850179
        },
        zoom: 16
      });
      var id1 = document.getElementById('textt');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(id1);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>abcr design</h1>
    <div id="options">
      <div id="o2">Histórico</div>
      <div id="o1"><a href="styletest.php">Tracking</a></div>
    </div>
```